# Possible to add options to a chainable query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4 methods, so the previous programmer built a query with `options` in a pure sql statement like this:

```
:conditions => 'a_table.an_attribute is NULL' + options
```

`options` is additional pure sql to add further refinement.

So as I convert this to newer methods, I cannot seem to get the syntax correct for `options` to work correctly like this:

```
self.joins(:tables1, :tables2).where(:something => :something_else).options
```

The `options` will be set with an if statement.

```
if true
   options = where(:attribute1 => :an_attribute)
else
   options = where(:attribute2 => :a_differant_attribute)
end
```

Is this doable or do I need to build separate full queries in different methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build up your conditions programmatically like so:

```
scope = joins(:tables1, :tables2).where(:something => :something_else)

if expression
  scope = scope.where(:attribute1 => :an_attribute)
else
  scope = scope.where(:attribute2 => :a_differant_attribute)
end
```

Comment: I settled on `scope :base_scope, -> {joins(:tables1, :tables2).where(:something => :something_else)}`  and then did as you recommended with adding it to the if statement. It works fine. Thanks.